Given the length of a word, how many character-level errors should we permit?
Using edit distance metrics, e.g. the Levenshtein-Damerau edit distance, words can easily be flagged as misspellings of other words.
However, the edit distance that constitutes a misspelling will obviously vary from word to word.  For example, in the case of words with length 3, if we have 3 character errors (replacements, for the sake of argument), this is obviously going to produce bad results, because all three letter words will be potential misspellings of each other.  On the other hand, in a 10 character long word, 3 character replacement errors would actually produce plausible corrections.
Obviously there is some relationship between the length of a word and how many character edits are permitted, but what exactly is this ratio?  For example, 30% of the word length might seem a good heuristic for how many edits should be allowed, but is there a standard ratio used in industry?

I am for len(str)//3 or round(len(str)/3)

I think you're trying to ask the wrong question here.  While I haven't used it in the context of spell-checking I have written something similar: Find jobs that are likely associates.  It's not a pure levenshtin approach because I know something of the data and the weight of a step isn't uniform.  I present the user a list of possibilities sorted by distance.  There was supposed to also be a manual select but we never got around to it because the right answer always appeared.  Years later it "broke" in a case with not quite so similar names and the objective turned out to be #21 while I was displaying 20 options.  Quick patch to 25 options, we still haven't gotten around to an alternative approach.
I would do spelling the same way--sort by distance, offer only the top entries.

This works if the spelling corrections are being presented to an annotator in the loop (or user), as described in your business case.  However, in my case I need to find potential spelling variants in a corpus of text.  This means I need to define a cutoff distance for each word length.

@SeánHealy Why?  At some point some human is going to have to evaluate it.  Until you get a really long word there are always going to be possible alternatives.


Why?
The end goal in my case is to both segment and correct the spelling in a corpus of sentences, where the writers often left out spacing between words.  I.e. I need a way to compare the quality of two string's similarities to known words, in order to determine which of these strings is the best option for segmentation.


@SeánHealy Still sounds like you want the closest strings even if you're going to use an automated tool.  (And I would run it through some sort of grammar parser, also--one version likely makes more sense than another.  I've never experimented in that realm to know the options.)

I tried putting it through a grammar parser, but the texts are littered with typos and this broke things… so it's important that the typos be dealt with before the parse can begin… in fact, I need to deal with the typos and the segmentation in one go.  In other words, I need to segment the texts in a divide and conquer style, selecting the sub-string that is the most likely token at each split.  For this reason, I need a way to compare how bad misspellings are across words of varying length.

@SeánHealy I would still think that whatever path produced the shortest distance would be the most likely one.

What if, for example, we have the string 'zicotes'.  If we we simply use the shortest distance to choose a segmentation here, then 'cat' or 'code' or 'ted' would be picked out first.  However, it would make more sense for 'zicotes' to be mapped to 'zygotes', given that an edit distance of 2 in a 7 character word is presumably better than an edit distance of 1 in words of length 3 or 4.  This is why I asked if there was an industry standard way of choosing the right edit distance per word length.

@SeánHealy I would think you would have to select with something like Levenshtein, inserting a space would be a possible operation.  I don't believe it's something where a standard could exist because it's a balance of two forces.  I don't think any other option exists that's two steps away, it would find the right answer.  And if that's an actual example I suspect an analysis of your data will show vowel-for-vowel is a more common mistake and thus put a lower cost on making such a step.
